# How to Send a Picture from My Flutter Application to a Flask Server Instance?

Tags: flutter

So I have a machine learning model that takes a picture and returns a prediction, I uploaded it to a flask server and tried tested it using a sample website that I created using HTML and it worked, but when I try to use it with a flutter app it doesn't work.. these are my codes. I am also getting this error in the depug consol when I try to upload a picture from my application

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://192.168.1.103:5000/prediction

Any help would be really appreciated.

> This is my python code that I created the flask instance in ( I run it on my cmd when I try to establish a connection using the flutter app)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as k

app = Flask(__name__)

model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", data="hey")


@app.route("/prediction", methods=["POST"])
def prediction():

    img = request.files['img']
    img.save("img.jpg")
    image = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224,224))
    image = np.reshape(image, (1,224,224,3))
    pred = model.predict(image)

    pred = pred > 0.5
    if(pred):
        predd="Malignant"
    else:
        predd="Benign"

    return jsonify({"prediction": predd,})
    
#this ip is my network's IPv4 ( I connected both my laptop and mobile
#to this WiFi while establishing the connection)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False,host='192.168.1.103',port=5000)
```

And this is the code I used in flutter to establish the connection

```
  sendImageToServer(File imageFile) async {
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
    stream.cast();
    var length = await imageFile.length();
    print(length);
    
    //this ip is my network's IPv4 ( I connected both my laptop and mobile
    //to this WiFi while establishing the connection) 

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.103:5000/prediction');
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
        filename:
            basename(imageFile.path));

    request.files.add(multipartFile);
    var response = await request.send();
    var result = await response.stream.bytesToString();

    final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson =
        json.decode(result.toString()) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    print(responseJson.toString());

    pre = responseJson["prediction"];
    print(pre);

    setState(() {
      prediction = pre;
    });
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    final image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    sendImageToServer(File(image.path));

    setState(() {
      fileImage = File(image.path);
      sendImageToServer(fileImage);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your flutter app ? if yes, can you kindly add your error log

Comment: No, I am not.. but the problem starts at this line of code "var response = await request.send();"

Comment: what is the statusCode of your response ? i want to know if the app is really accessing your local server, because it may be a firewall problem. And also how did you know it from that line ? did it throw an exception ?

Comment: How do I know the statusCode?
I knew it was at this line because I changed the value of string that holds the prediction after each line of code in this function and the string was holding the value I assigned to it before this line.. that's how I reached this thought

Comment: print(response.statusCode); after that line and tell me what you got,

Comment: I will try it now.. thanks a lot

Comment: I didn't get any output when I tried it.. but I got this error
" E/flutter (29531): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://192.168.1.103:5000/prediction"   in the debug console.. I don't know if it helps figure out the problem!

Comment: try changing the url to start with "https" instead of "http" keda, also add this error to your question

Comment: I will.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the error you got, if changing http to https didn't work try this:
in your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`  add the following:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

Comment: I tried this and the error had gone but it still doesn't work.. however this is the statusCode I am getting :  400

Comment: and this is the error I got " Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)"

Comment: well that's one step ahead, this means that the app can speak with the server. also try running in debug mode to see the values and detect where the problem is. one final thing, if the answer has fixed your problem kindly accept it as the right answer.

Comment: this 400 status code may be a missing headers problem

Comment: what do you mean by headers problem? { I accepted the answer :) }

Comment: meaning that you need to tell the server what content he's expecting, authorization, etc. so try adding this line before sending the request, ```request.headers["Content-Type"]='multipart/form-data';```

Comment: actually i just read the docs, it says it adds these headers automatically, try searching for the problem instead it will help you more than i do :D. or post another question if struggled finding a solution.مصر ام الدنيا :D

Comment: maybe the problem is in the body itself, make sure you're reading the file correctly. that's all i know to help you i'm sorry